# Appropriateness of a Classification Tree for data with repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, cart, assumptions

I am looking at modeling a categorical response that has multiple measurements per "product" using a classification tree. Each product can have up to three measurements in the dataset, essentially one per each team that measured it with some products not being available to some teams. Because not all observations are technically independent, I am wondering if it is appropriate to fit a classification tree to this data as is?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's acceptable if you

1. choose a tree method with hyperparameters that can control overfitting (for example gamma and tree depth in xgboost)
2. define the cross validation folds such that observations from a product are all in the same fold.